# CGI scripts are not working on lighttpd with SSL

Tags: ssl, lighttpd, cgi

CGI scripts worked perfectly, while I was using **HTTP**. Then I set **redirecting** for all traffic through **https** and now CGI doesn't work at all (**404** - not found). I use *lighttpd* server.

Here is the  part of *lighttpd.conf* for redirect:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1" )
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**: [lighttpd.conf (click me)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4b2e1c9f6e394f56f3d2)

**EDIT 2**: [mod_fastcgi.conf (click me)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/20f268cd5b757c4171f0)

Comment: The redirect looks fine, for everything else you didn't provide enough details. Basically it "should" still work if it worked before.

Comment: Could you list also mod_fastcgi.conf ?

Comment: Ok, have done it. See edit 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure CGI and documentroot for the SSL listener too.

Comment: But everything except cgi works.

Comment: I have the following lines in lighttpd.conf:
    
    `server.port = 443`
    
    `server.document-root = var.basedir + "/htdocs"`

Comment: Could you please post the entire config?

Comment: Can you also add the relevant section of the lighttpd logs?

Comment: I've added config file, see edit 1